# Dataframe concatenation with same indexes and different column sizes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

How can I concatenate a dictionary of dataframes (index of each dataframe starts with 0. So, there are duplicate indices) with different column sizes. i.e. Few df's have some missing columns and some df's contain all the columns.

Here is an example:

df1

```
idx col1 col2 col3
0    1     1    1
1    2     2    2
```

df2

```
idx col1 col3 
0    1     1    
1    2     2
```

df3

```
idx col1 col2 col3
0    1     1    1
1    2     2    2
```

desired_result

```
idx col1 col2 col3
 0    1     1    1
 1    2     2    2
 2    1     nan  1
 3    2     nan  2
 4    1     1    1
 5    2     2    2
```

So I would like to fill these columns with Nans and reshape it to the dataframe having all columns.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the dictionary of dataframes looks like the following

```
df_dict = {
    'df1': pd.DataFrame({'idx': [1, 2], 'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [1, 2], 'col3': [1, 2]}),
    'df2': pd.DataFrame({'idx': [1, 2], 'col1': [1, 2], 'col3': [1, 2]}),
    'df3': pd.DataFrame({'idx': [1, 2], 'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [1, 2], 'col3': [1, 2]})
}
```

One can simply use [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) as follows

```
df = pd.concat(df_dict.values(), ignore_index=True)

[Out]:

   idx  col1  col2  col3
0    1     1   1.0     1
1    2     2   2.0     2
2    1     1   NaN     1
3    2     2   NaN     2
4    1     1   1.0     1
5    2     2   2.0     2
```

If one wants the `idx` column to be the index, one can pass [`pandas.DataFrame.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) as follows

```
df = pd.concat(df_dict.values(), ignore_index=True).set_index('idx')

[Out]:

     col1  col2  col3
idx                  
1       1   1.0     1
2       2   2.0     2
1       1   NaN     1
2       2   NaN     2
1       1   1.0     1
2       2   2.0     2
```

---

**Notes:**

- If one doesn't want `col2` to be `float64` ([following this user's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74774022/dataframe-concatenation-with-same-indexes-and-different-column-sizes/74774385?noredirect=1#comment131966445_74774385)), one approach would be to use [`pandas.Int64Dtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Int64Dtype.html) as follows

  ```
  df['col2'] = df['col2'].astype(pd.Int64Dtype())

  [Out]:

     idx  col1  col2  col3
  0    1     1     1     1
  1    2     2     2     2
  2    1     1  <NA>     1
  3    2     2  <NA>     2
  4    1     1     1     1
  5    2     2     2     2
  ```

Comment: main = pd.concat(dict_main.values(), ignore_index=True).. I already tried this..But I got this error.

Comment: @SherwinR then your dictionary of df might not look like the one you mention in the question, and, consequently, the one I share in the answer.

Comment: @GonçaloPeres, just out of interest, why is *col2* merging as a *float*? And could this be an *int*?

Comment: @Bossman `NaN` is a float. An alternative could be the [`pandas.Int64Dtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Int64Dtype.html) as it allows nullable ints.